# I got this formula but can anyone prove it

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

Yesterday while doing some questions, I came across a formula that if a wire with uniform resistance R is made into n sided regular polygon then the net resistance between any two corners with $x-1$ vertices in between is

$$R_{net} =\frac{Rx(n-x)} {n^2} $$

It's just written in my book with no proof. I have tried proving it but could not. I want the physics behind it rather than just the formula. I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/478964/2451

Comment: @Satwik Hello Satwik  I recommend you to post the proof on this website.

Comment: Hi Satwik. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you've made an $n$ sided polygon out of a wire of resistance $R$. Each segment of the polygon therefore has resistance $R/n$. If there are $x - 1 $ vertices between two points, we have basically formed a parallel circuit where one branch has $x$ segments and one has $n - x$. We then use the formula for a parallel resistance:
$$
\frac{1}{R_\mathrm{total}} = \frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2}
$$
$R_1 = x R/n$ and $R_2 = (n - x) R/n$. As a result:
$$
\frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2} = \frac{n}{x R} + \frac{n}{ (n - x) R} = \frac{n(n -x)R + nx R}{(n -x)x R^2} = \frac{n^2}{(n -x )x R}
$$

Finally, inverting this yields the following formula:
$$
R_\mathrm{total} = \frac{ R x (n-x)}{n^2}
$$

I don't see what an even number of sides has to do with it, but maybe I'm missing some obvious geometry.

Comment: Agreed, the formula appears to be general, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Yeah i guess nothing to do with even sides